# how to give hyper link to a word within paragraph in android

Tags: android, hyperlink, paragraph

I know how to give a hyper link to word, but now i need to give hyperlink to a word within a paragraph ?

For example my paragraph:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and "typesetting industry". Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

Here i want to add hyper link to "typesetting industry" this word 
, is that possible?? if so please help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could do this using below code,

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.");

        MatchFilter mMatchFilter = new MatchFilter() {
            public final boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        TransformFilter mTransformFilter = new TransformFilter() {
            public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url) {
                return "www.google.com";
            }
        };

        Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("typesetting industry");
        String scheme = "http://";
        Linkify.addLinks(textView, mPattern, scheme, mMatchFilter, mTransformFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear Brindha use this for a particular text,you can set web or email or phone or map or all as per your requirement.

android:autoLink="web|email|phone|map|all"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as i need to give separate link to diff words in a paragraph the first answer helped me.